# Dart / Flutter - populating parameters in objects in a list of maps with values from a map of maps (conditional merging of two maps)

Tags: list, dictionary, dart, flutter

This is the code that's not producing the desired populating / merging:

```
List<Quote> result2 = result.map((entry) => Quote.fromMap(entry)).toList();
      print('result1: $result2');
      result2.forEach((item) => item = Quote.fromMap(model.productData[item.riskType]));
      print('result2: $result2');
```

The two print statements result in the same unchanged list with properties from the model not populating the result2 objects (i.e. the relevant properties in the objects are remaining null rather than values from the model). The model and its properties (`model.productData[item.riskType]`) are visible and print to the console properly.

```
print('${Quote.fromMap(model.productData[item.riskType])}');
```

shows the parameters that are not being added, while the existing values are all `null`.

I've been trying to figure out how to effectively combine the two sources to form full objects in the list.

The code to add to item is probably incorrect in the `forEach`, but not sure how to correct it. Any thoughts anyone?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve, are you trying to converts map to objects and filter them based on specific value?

Comment: Yep, correct, it would be good to understand how to do that in dart/flutter